# Postman stuck at "Sending request..."

Tags: node.js, json, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create an instance "note" of Note.js (model)

by sending a post request via postman raw json

```
{
    "user": "645xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx88d",
    "title": "title",
    "text": "description"
}
```

it's stuck at line:
`const note = await Note.create({ user })`   in notes controller

there is an if(note) return response after this line but it doesn't seem to reach there.

I I think the code is fine since i've been following a tutorial.
I do have `app.use(express.json());` in server.js file.
`console.log(Note.create(noteObject))` outputs `Promise { <pending> }`

UPDATE:

so apparently, commenting out the commented code in this Node.js file makes it run fine. But I shouldn't have to do so. what's going wrong, how to fix it?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose)

const noteSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        text: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        completed: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    },
    {
       timestamps: true
    }
)

//noteSchema.plugin(AutoIncrement, {
//    inc_field: 'ticket',
//    id: 'ticketNums',
//    start_seq: 500
//})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Note', noteSchema)
```

controller file utilises 'express-async-handler',
mongoErrLog.log and errLog.log files have no updates but reqLog.log file logs the following entry:

`POST /notes  undefined`

Comment: Check in catch block, and share what's the error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a known issue between mongoose-sequence and the latest mongoose version:
https://github.com/ramiel/mongoose-sequence/issues/133

You can downgrade your mongoose version to a compatible one, e.g. `npm i mongoose@6.5.0`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same exact problem and looks like it's from the Mongoose version, The solution is either to downgrade the version of Mongoose to 6.5 or instead of **Mongoose-sequence** use **Typegoose/auto-increment** ( **npm i  @typegoose/auto-increment** )  and here is the code with solution:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const { AutoIncrementID } = require('@typegoose/auto-increment');

const noteSchema = new Schema(
    {
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'User',
        },
        ticket: {
            type: Number,
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        text: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        completed: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

noteSchema.plugin(AutoIncrementID, {
    field: 'ticket',
    incrementBy: 1,
    startAt: 500,
    trackerCollection: 'counters',
    trackerModelName: 'notes',
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Note', noteSchema);
```